# Postcode search that affects a change when input value contains specific characters

Tags: jquery, string, substring, postal-code

I'm attempting to create a simple postcode search. I have been able to affect a change when the input value contains only the first two letter of each postcode, as defined in the variables.

```
var AB = "AB";
var AL = "AL";
```

However when a full postcode is entered, containing extra characters than the defined variables, no change is made. How do I need to structure the variables so they look for an input value that only contains the defined characters.

[JSFiddle of what I have so far](https://jsfiddle.net/garyvoss/vrL2roas/)

Answer (score 0):

Multiple variables is redundant for what you're trying to do, use multi-dimensional array and loop through each. Solution on [jsFiddle here

```js
$('.find').click(function() {

  var text = $("#distancePostcode").val().toLowerCase();
  var PostCode = {
    'AB': 'test1',
    'AL': 'test2'
  }

  for (var key in PostCode) {
    if (key.toLowerCase().indexOf(text) > -1) {
      for (var key2 in PostCode) {
        $('#' + PostCode[key2]).css("background", "");
      }
      $('#' + PostCode[key]).css("background", "red");
      break;
    }
  }

});
```

```css
.test {
  margin: 10px 0px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" placeholder="Postcode" id="distancePostcode"> <a class="find">find</a> 
<div class="test" id="test1">test 1</div>
<div class="test" id="test2">test 2</div>
```

][1](https://jsfiddle.net/oLfbhn6b/)